# SPARQL query for specific information

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am struggling a lot to create some SPARQL queries. I need 3 specific things, and this is what i have so far:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select distinct ?title ?author ?country ?genre ?language
where {
  ?s rdf:type dbo:Book;
  dbp:title ?title;
  dbp:author ?author;
  dbp:country ?country;
  dbp:genre ?genre;
  dbp:language ?language.

}
```

This query will bring me a list of all books. What i really need is the ability to add some filters to this code. There are 3 things i want to filter by:

- specific title name (e.g., search for title with "harry potter")
- specific author name (e.g., search for author with "J. K. Rowling")
- specific genre (e.g., search for genre with "adventure")

I've been struggling with this for too long and i simply cannot define these 3 queries. I am trying to implement a function that will execute a SPARQL statement using parameters passed by an user form. I found a few examples here and in the web but i just cannot build these 3 specific queries.

Comment: you want to find books by some string given? use a REGEX on the labels of the resources that represent the filter criteria. even better, use `bif:contains`. for example, get the English label of the author and then do a filter on it.

Comment: You'll also want to look at the description of an example of the thing you want to find, such as <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire>. (How long is "too long"? This feels a lot like last-minute efforts at homework...)

Comment: This "too long" that you ironically mentioned is like one month. I had to create a lot of stuff for a new website system that uses system recommendation, user interface, etc etc but i simply cannot understand RDF/SPARQL. This is the only missing piece in my project. Currently i can execute the SPARQL that i listed above and populate the web page with the information retrieved from this query, but i need some specific queries that will return the same columns so i can populate the search page with specific results. I want to be able to specify author genre OR name that will come from site input

Comment: @AKSW i saw an example from you which allows to search for specific book title, but even with that example i just cannot see how to build the query for those 3 purposes. More than that, i don't know how to receive only those fields (instead of SELECT *). I am not good with RDF/SPARQL, but thanks for the suggestion anyways.

Comment: Minimized example :`select *
where {
  ?s rdf:type dbo:Book;
  dbo:author ?author .
 ?author rdfs:label ?authorLabel .
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?authorLabel), 'en'))
?authorLabel bif:contains "Rowling"
}`

Comment: More human-readable: `select (str(?bookLabel) as ?title) (str(?authorLabel) as ?author)
where {
  ?s rdf:type dbo:Book .
 ?s rdfs:label ?bookLabel .
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?bookLabel), 'en'))

  ?s dbo:author ?author .
 ?author rdfs:label ?authorLabel .
FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?authorLabel), 'en'))
?authorLabel bif:contains "Rowling"
}`

Comment: Regarding the other properties -> not every resource has every property, not every book has every property. check example books, e.g. http://dbpedia.org/page/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher's_Stone

Answer (score 3):

As noted, not every book has every property, and some of your properties may not exist at all.  For instance, I changed `dbp:genre` to `dbo:literaryGenre`, based on the description of [Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire).  See [query form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%20%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3ABook%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FbookLabel%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FbookLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Aauthor%20%3Fauthor%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fauthor%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FauthorLabel%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FauthorLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3FauthorLabel%20bif%3Acontains%20%22Rowling%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbp%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FcountryLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbo%3AliteraryGenre%20%3Fgenre%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fgenre%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FgenreLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FgenreLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbp%3Alanguage%20%3Flanguage%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Flanguage%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlanguageLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FlanguageLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), and [results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%7B%20%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20dbo%3ABook%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fs%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FbookLabel%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FbookLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fs%20dbo%3Aauthor%20%3Fauthor%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fauthor%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FauthorLabel%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FauthorLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%3FauthorLabel%20bif%3Acontains%20%22Rowling%22%20%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbp%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FcountryLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbo%3AliteraryGenre%20%3Fgenre%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fgenre%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FgenreLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FgenreLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fs%20dbp%3Alanguage%20%3Flanguage%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Flanguage%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlanguageLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3FlanguageLabel%29%2C%20%27en%27%29%29%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20).

```
SELECT *
WHERE
 { ?s rdf:type dbo:Book .
   ?s rdfs:label ?bookLabel . 
      FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?bookLabel), 'en')) 
   ?s dbo:author ?author . 
   ?author rdfs:label ?authorLabel . 
      FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?authorLabel), 'en')) 
   ?authorLabel bif:contains "Rowling" 
   OPTIONAL { ?s dbp:country ?country .
              ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?countryLabel), 'en')) }
   OPTIONAL { ?s dbo:literaryGenre ?genre .
              ?genre rdfs:label ?genreLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?genreLabel), 'en')) }
   OPTIONAL { ?s dbp:language ?language .
              ?language rdfs:label ?languageLabel .
                 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?languageLabel), 'en')) }
}
```